# ODM XU Plugin - event listener

Tags: ibm-odm

I've been trying to build an ODM Rule Execution Server XU plugin that logs details about the various events that are fired during rule execution. I've tried implementing the `IlrRuleEngineEventPlugin` interface and extending `EventPlugin` (neither approach worked). I've added a reference to my plugin (com.mypackage.MyPlugin) to **ra.xml**:

```
<config-property>
<config-property-name>plugins</config-property-name>
<config-property-type>java.lang.String</config-property-type>
<config-property-value>
    {pluginClass=Management,xuName=default,protocol=jmx},
    {pluginClass=DVS},
    {pluginClass=HTDS},
    {pluginClass=Event,EventDestinationType=Topic,EventDestinationConnectionFactoryName=jms/WbeTopicConnectionFactory,EventDestinationName=jms/eventDestination},
    {pluginClass=com.mypackage.MyPlugin,foo=bar,fiz=baz}
    </config-property-value>
</config-property>
```

... and I've enabled **ruleset.trace.enabled** and **ruleset.sequential.trace.enabled** ruleset properties.

... but my plugin is never invoked.

What are the steps that are required to implement a RES XU event listener plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of a default install of ODM on WebSphere, you have to modify this line in [WEBSPHERE-ROOT]\AppServer\profiles\ODMSample8810\config\cells\SamplesCell\nodes\SamplesNode\resources.xml

```
<resourceProperties 
    xmi:id="J2EEResourceProperty_1501875435118" 
    name="plugins" type="java.lang.String"
    value="{
        pluginClass=Management,xuName=default,protocol=jmx},
        {pluginClass=DVS},
        {pluginClass=HTDS},
        {pluginClass=Event,EventDestinationType=Topic,EventDestinationConnectionFactoryName=jms/WbeTopicConnectionFactory,EventDestinationName=jms/eventDestination},
        {pluginClass=com.mypackage.MyPlugin,foo=bar,fiz=baz}" 
    required="false" 
    ignore="false" 
    confidential="false" 
    supportsDynamicUpdates="false"/>
```

Stop and start WebSphere and you should see your plugin being loaded.